# Checking all the Checkboxes in a certain row by giving the row number in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, checkbox

I have Created Checkboxes like this:
[image]

but now i want to be able to check all the Checkboxes in one Row after giving the Row number

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBox[,] c = new CheckBox[10, 5];
        for (i = 1; i < c.GetLength(0); i++)
        {

            for ( j = 1; j < c.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                c[i, j] = new CheckBox();
                c[i, j].Location = new Point(i * 50, j * 50);

                c[i, j].AutoSize = true;

                c[i, j].Name = i + "-" + j.ToString();
                c[i, j].Text = i + "-" + j.ToString();
                this.Controls.Add(c[i, j]);


            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You already use name:

```
for (i = 1; i < c.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for ( j = 1; j < c.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        ...

        c[i, j].Name = i + "-" + j.ToString();

        this.Controls.Add(c[i, j]);
    }
}
```

So you could create a method to search against that:

```
private CheckBox Find(int row, int col)
{
    foreach(var control in this.Controls)
    {
        if (control is CheckBox && control.Name == $"{row}-{col}")
            return control as CheckBox;
    }
}
```

So then just loop the rows and/or columns you want. This should check every even row:

```
for(var i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        for(var j = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
        {
             var checkBox = Find(i, j);

             if (checkBox != null)
                 checkBox.Checked = true;
        }
    } 
}
```

It's not the most efficient as each `Find` call is essentially looping over the controls so you'd be iterating multiple times but should work for a reasonable grid.

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution would use a jagged array instead, but with 2D array you can do the following:

You should change your check box array initialisation to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < c.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        c[i, j] = new CheckBox
        {
            Location = new Point(i * 50, j * 50),
            AutoSize = true,
            Name = i + "-" + j.ToString(),
            Text = i + "-" + j.ToString()
        };
        Controls.Add(c[i, j]);
    }
}
```

If you still want their location to not be the upper left corner you can add 1 to the index like this:

```
Location = new Point((i + 1) * 50, (j + 1) * 50)
```

Than you can later obtain a row like this:

```
private CheckBox[] GetCheckBoxsByRow(int row, CheckBox[,] checkboxs)
{
    CheckBox[] selectedRowCheckboxs = new CheckBox[checkboxs.GetLength(0)];
    for (int x = 0; x < checkboxs.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        selectedRowCheckboxs[x] = checkboxs[x, row - 1];
    }
    return selectedRowCheckboxs;
}
```

Example usage:

```
var firstRow = GetCheckBoxsByRow(1, c);
```